# What datatype should I use for storing large text files and binary data in SQLite in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to store some binary files (spreadsheets) and some web pages in my table in SQLite DB in Rails. I know that storing files in the DB isn't a good practice but in this case, the convenience outweighs all else since I only need to store files rarely. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `binary` data type maps to to the `BLOB` in SQLite. The size can be specified by using the `limit` parameter. Here's an example from an `self.up` method of a migration:

```
t.column :mystuff, :binary, :limit => 10.megabyte
```

Comment: I also read that SQlite has a maximum size limit of 1MB for BLOBS. It can be increased but one would have re-compile the SQLite sources with a particular flag.

Comment: the maximum size is documented as 1GB per the sqlite documentation found here http://sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`BLOB`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) type for this purpose.

Comment: Thats a link to MySQL's BLOB type Mridang asked about SQLite. Here is a better link http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html